# How to rotate/pan Blender viewport like the Meshlab trackball?

Tags: 3d-view

I find rotating with the mouse (middle-click+drag) very unnatural in Blender (2.8).

How can I make it work the same as in Meshlab (which rotates around a track ball)?

Answer (score 2):

There's a setting for that under *Main Menu > Edit > Preferences > Navigation Tab > Orbit & Pan* choose: *Orbit Method: Trackball*

[image]

Otherwise Blender will constrain you to turntable rotation, which does not allow full free rotation around all axes (it keeps the Z-axis upright while rotating).